# Observable.subscribe() not working in IE on component change in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two HTML buttons 'previous' and 'next'. I have different tabs (components) to which I navigate to using these buttons. The code works as expected in Chrome and Firefox but it gives a blank screen when clicking next and previous buttons in IE or Edge.

'next' button event handler:

```js
saveAndNextClick(form: FormGroup, section: string) {
  this.markFormGroupTouched(form);
  if (form) {
    if (section === 'lastsection') {
      this.sectionChangeService.change('schoolSection');
    } else {
      this.hideShowTabSection();
      this.selectedSectionGroup[section] = false;
    }
  }
  this.saveData(); 
  this.saveService.saveQuestion();
}
```

Template

```
<div class="d-flex app-question-navigation justify-content-between">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary buttonSize (click)="previousClick(appSectionThree,'sectionTwo')">
    Previous
  </a>
  <span class="app-question-pagination">Section 3 of 8</span>
  <a class="btn btn-secondary buttonSize" (click)="saveAndNextClick(appSectionThree,'sectionFour')">
    Next
  </a>
</div>
</form>
```

component.ts

````js
ngOnInit() {
  this.sectionChangeService.listen().subscribe((message: any) => {
    if (message.text === 'prvsparentdemosection') {
      this.saveAndNextClick(this.pdemographicsSectionFive, 'sectionFour');
    }
  });
}

Service:

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class SectionChangeService {
  private listner = new Subject<any>();

  change(message: string) {
    this.listner.next({ text: message });
  }

  clearListner() {
    this.listner.next();
  }

  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return this.listner.asObservable();
  }
}
````

Comment: Did you see any error or warning in the browser console? If yes, please let us know about that error. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT 
I don't see anything in the console, no errors

Comment: Is your project get to run in IE 11 or it also shows the blank page? I can see the arrow function in the code. So did you added the necessary polyfills or use Babel to transpile the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using polyfills, they are necessary for IE & Edge because they lack some es6/7 functions

Import this in the polyfills.ts file

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';`
```